# UCM service for searching in all revisions

Tags: content-management-system, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I would like to search for a text in an attribute of UCM content using RIDC. If I use GET_SEARCH_RESULTS service, I will be getting only the latest revision the of result document. But I want to get all the revisions, which will fall in to the given search criteria. is there any way for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code is here..

```
        String whereClause = "UPPER(XCOMMENTS) LIKE '%VALUE%'";
        dataBinder.putLocal("IdcService", "GET_DATARESULTSET");
        dataBinder.putLocal("dataSource", "Documents");
        dataBinder.putLocal("whereClause", whereClause);
        dataBinder.putLocal("resultName", "YourResult");
        ServiceResponse response =
            idcClient.sendRequest(userContext, dataBinder);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        DataBinder serverBinder = response.getResponseAsBinder();
        DataResultSet resultSet = serverBinder.getResultSet("YourResult");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to search for against full-text or metadata?

If metadata, you should be able to use service [GET_DATARESULTSET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e11011/c05_core002.htm#CSSRG2117) and dataSource *RevisionIDs*.

If full-text, you might need to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I want to search on metadata only. I used the suggested service but Datasource as Documents. It worked to search on metadata.